# Regular expression to find characters when there but ignore when not

Tags: regex

Please help. I am trying to come up with a regular expression that will always find a matches to the bold text. The problem is that some files names will have a "-n" and others will not.

> test_Index_**060215**_E01.pdf
>   test_Index_**060215-1**_E01.pdf

I have tried:

```
test_Index_+([0-1]+[0-9]+[0-3]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+)_E01.pdf
```

but it only works to find
060215

and

```
test_Index_+([0-1]+[0-9]+[0-3]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+\D+\d+)_E01.pdf
```

only finds
060215-1

I have not been able to get a match for both with one expression. Can someone help with with an expression that will always pull a result with the file name structure I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
test_Index_([\d-]+)
```

Or you can use a negated character class which I would prefer:

```
test_Index_([^_]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will work using your strict formatting rules:

```
^test_Index_([01]\d[0-3]\d{3}(?:-\d+)?)_E01\.pdf$
```

Here is an example on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dA9iS8/3).

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
^test_Index_\d+-{0,1}\d*_E01\.pdf$
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/uD2mE4/1)

Also, if you want it to be more precise (since it looks like you are matching a date) you could do this:

```
^test_Index_\d{6}-{0,1}\d*_E01\.pdf$
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/nS4tN6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the lazy quantifier `?` as it denotes the following:

> Matches 0 or 1 of the preceding token, effectively making it optional.

Meaning if you specify the match group for -1 or any digit as optional:

```
(-\d)?
```

Thus you will get a regular expression like so:

```
test_Index_(\d{6})(-\d)?_E01\.pdf
```

Also make sure you understand the use of the `+` token and that you escape periods.